# HSLS float1,..., float4 and its fields

Tags: directx-11, hlsl

I see that HSLS has float and a number after float (1-4) and a lot of fields (r, rr, rrrr, arar,...) (I see these fields with the help of [HLSL Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41632187/4608491) Thanks to Tim Jones :D - I can't imagine (for now) how can we programming HSLS without this tool).

I try to find references about this data type and its field but I can't find anything about it(why the number 1-4 and the meanings of its fields. In C++ float is just float number, here, what is float)

Below is my progress so far:

According to [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509646(v=vs.85).aspx)

> float - 32-bit floating point value.
>
> For example, here is a 4-component signed-normalized float-variable declaration.
>
> `snorm float4 fourComponentIEEEFloat;`

It doesn't answer my question: What does this code mean

```
RWTexture2D<float4> testTexture         : register(u0);

[numthreads(@value( threads_per_group_x ), @value( threads_per_group_y ), @value( threads_per_group_z ))]
void main
(
    uint3 gl_LocalInvocationID : SV_GroupThreadID,
    uint3 gl_GlobalInvocationID : SV_DispatchThreadId
)
{
    testTexture[gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy].xyzw = float4( float2(gl_LocalInvocationID.xy) / 16.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
}
```

I may slightly understand that float2(gl_LocalInvocationID.xy) is 2 float

```
testTexture[gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy].xyzw = float4( float2(gl_LocalInvocationID.xy) / 16.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
```

is equal

```
testTexture[gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy].xyzw = float4(gl_LocalInvocationID.x / 16.0f, gl_LocalInvocationID.y / 16.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

But I don't know if it's right, beside, how about fields r, rr, rrrr, arar,... I mention earlier.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These fields are no real fields, but Source Register Swizzling ([doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb219869%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)).

A `float4` is a four-component float vector, where the components are x, y, z and w. As float4 is often used as a color as well, these components can also be addressed by r, g, b and a (So .xyzw is equivalent to .rgba).

Source swizzling enables you to swap, reduce or repeat components inline, so if you only need the xy component of your `float3 vec` you can just write `vec.xy` instead of something like `float2(vec.x, vec.y)`. If you want to swap color channels of your `float4 color` for some computation you can easily write `color.bgra` to swap the red and blue component for example. And finally you can also duplicate channels, such as `vec.xxxx` to get a `float4` with `vec.x` in all four components. Combining these methods is also allowed, such as `vec.yzxx`.